# Is it possible to do summation of a derivative?

Tags: calculus, summation

For example, let's say you want to add a sequence of terms, each succeeding term being the derivative of the previous.

ex: the term is x<sup>4</sup>, and you want to add 4 derivatives of it in a sequence of terms.( = 4x<sup>3</sup>+12x<sup>2</sup>+24x+24 )

What would the notation for this be? If possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I'd write $$\sum_{n=1}^k f^{(n)}(x)$$ where for your example you'd have $k=4$ and $f(x) = x^4$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment
rather than an answer.

Note that,
by Liebnitz's rule,
$(e^x f(x))^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} e^xf^{(k)}(x)
$
so
$e^{-x}(e^x f(x))^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}(x)
$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to
actually do a summation:

Since
$f(x+h)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{h^n f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}
$,
by setting
$h=1$
we get
$f(x+1)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}
$.